# Regex to get parts of URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, url

Hi I have URL as follows:

- vimeo.com/99612902
- www.vimeo.com/99612902
- http://vimeo.com/99612902
- http://www.vimeo.com/99612902
- http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=81368903

I need to parse the above URL to get two group as folloes:

```
Group1                 Group 2
vimeo.com/             99612902
www.vimeo.com/         99612902
http://vimeo.com/      99612902
http://www.vimeo.com/  99612902
http://vimeo.com/      81368903
```

I've tried the followin regex

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)(:([^\/]*))?((\/[\w\-]+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

but which yields me unwanted and empty group. Please help me out.

Comment: Does this need to be a regex?  Can you use the System.Uri class and then get the sections out via that?

Comment: do you want to validate the url as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your input, we can match both parts into Groups 1 and 2 with this:

```
^(.*/)(.*)
```

or, for your revised input:

```
^(.*[/=])([^/=]+$)
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/54), see the capture groups in the right pane.

In VB.NET, you can do this:

```
Dim theUrl As String
Dim theNumbers As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "^(.*/)(.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    theUrl = ResultString.Groups(1).Value
    theNumbers = ResultString.Groups(2).Value
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

**Option 2**

If you want to do some very lightweight url validation at the same time, you can use this:

```
^((?:http://)?(?:www\.)?[^./]+\.\w+/)(.*)
```

or, with your revised input:

```
^((?:http://)?(?:www\.)?[^./]+\.\w+[=/])([^/=]+$)
```

Comment: @Braj Actually in my code i validate the URL in some part, even though this regex will vlidate URL means it would be good

Comment: I added a second option to do some lightweight url validation if you want to do that at the same time. As you know urls can have all shapes and forms, so this is not really a solid url validator for all kinds of weather. Every url regex will have pros and cons. :)

Comment: IMO the best sites are rexegg.com and regular-expressions.info... But the best, if you have the time, is to read Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd Ed and The Regular Expressions Cookbook. Then play with regex in a variety of engines. It sounds like you're hooked, you'll be a pro in no time. :)

Comment: Hi if i have link `http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=82422002` like this it shoul give group1 as `http://vimeo.com/` and group2 as `82422002` , but not getting like this

Comment: Added an option that will work for your revised input: `^(.*[/=])([^/=]+$)`

Comment: And this for the basic validator `^((?:http://)?(?:www\.)?[^./]+\.\w+[=/])([^/=]+$)`

Comment: Sorry first one takes group 1 as `http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=` and group2 as `82422002.` Second one not matching..

Comment: I see the problem, sorry, hadn't tested it. (Still trying to start a movie. :) Please try this. `^((?:http://)?(?:www\.)?[^./]+\.\S+[=/])([^/=]+$)` Thx for accepting the answer btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could use the below regex,

```
^(.*\/)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bR2jE1/2)

From the starting upto the last `/` symbol are captured by group1. Remaining characters are captured into group2.

**OR**

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^.]*)\.\w+\/)(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bR2jE1/3)

Comment: OP wants to validate the URL see comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to validate the url then try this as well. Get the matched group from index 1 and 2.

```
(.*?[^\/]*\/)(\d+)
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lF4hM6/17)

String literals for use in programs: C#

```
@"(.*?[^\/]*\/)(\d+)"
```